# How do you annotate the type of an abstract class with mypy?

Tags: python-3.x, types, abstract-class, mypy

I'm writing a library where I need a method that takes a (potentially) abstract type, and returns an instance of a concrete subtype of that type:

```
# script.py
from typing import Type
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod


class AbstractClass(ABC):
    @abstractmethod
    def abstract_method(self):
        pass

T = TypeVar('T', bound=AbstractClass)

def f(c: Type[T]) -> T:
    # find concrete implementation of c based on
    # environment configuration
    ...


f(AbstractClass)  # doesn't type check
```

Running `mypy script.py` yields:

`error: Only concrete class can be given where "Type[AbstractClass]" is expected`

I don't understand this error message and am having a hard time finding any documentation for it. Is there any way to annotate the function so that `mypy` will type check this?

As a side note, PyCharm's type checker, which is what I use the most, type checks `f` with no errors.

Comment: Your example doesn't make any sense to me:  `f` is not even using its argument.  Can you please clarify what you are trying to achieve?   If your goal is to pointlessly pass an abstract class to a function then, yes, mypy will raise an error, and until you can demonstrate a reason to do this, then I have to agree that it's the right behavior.

Comment: You've declared that the type of the argument passed in to `f` is the same as the type of the instance returned from `f`, but then you pass in an `AbstractClass` and expect to get back a `ConcreteClass` instance?  Flesh out the example a bit more.  Store the result of `f(AbstractClass)` and describe what you think the type should be.  It sounds like you want mypy to think that the result is a `AbstractClass` instance, while at runtime its actually a `ConcreteClass` instance, but I'm still pretty unclear on your expectations.

Comment: The specific use case I have is to have `f` behave as a factory method/dependency injection mechanism based on some environment configuration. The totality of it is a little too involved to put here, created a (simplifed) gist instead https://gist.github.com/suned/321725213d81065ac5c22e734ebd9d9e.

Comment: ok, that makes more sense.  I came up with something that produces the desired result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There exists a [github issue](https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/4717) about this misbehaviour (IMHO) in mypy. Basically, `Type[_T]` with `_T` being a TypeVar will never accept an abstract class.

The only sane solution I have seen is disabling this error, for example by including this in the `mypy.ini` file:

```ini
[mypy]
# Allows Type[T] to refer to abstract classes, which is not otherwise supported.
# See https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/4717
disable_error_code = type-abstract
```

Quoting [from the discussion](https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/4717#issuecomment-1421078742):

> Now that #14619 was merged, would disabling the type-abstract error code by default address all the main issues, or is there something else that would need to be done?

I'll add my 2¢ to the ticket later and hope, they will iron this out.

Answer (score 8):

It does appear that mypy is a bit biased against using an abstract base class this way, though as you demonstrate there are valid use cases.

You can work around this by making your factory function a class method on your abstract class.  If stylistically you'd like to have a top-level function as a factory, then you can create an alias to the class method.

```
from typing import TYPE_CHECKING
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod


class AbstractClass(ABC):
    @abstractmethod
    def abstract_method(self):
        raise NotImplementedError

    @classmethod
    def make_concrete(cls) -> 'AbstractClass':
        """
        find concrete implementation based on environment configuration
        """
        return A()


class A(AbstractClass):
    def abstract_method(self):
        print("a")

# make alias
f = AbstractClass.make_concrete
x = f()
if TYPE_CHECKING:
    reveal_type(x)  # AbstractClass
```

Note that, without more work, mypy cannot know which concrete class is created by the factory function, it will only know that it is compatible with `AbstractClass`, as demonstrated by the output of `reveal_type`.

Alternately, if you're willing to give up the runtime checking provided by `abc.ABC`, you can get something even closer to your original design:

```
from typing import TYPE_CHECKING
from abc import abstractmethod


class AbstractClass:  # do NOT inherit from abc.ABC
    @abstractmethod
    def abstract_method(self):
        raise NotImplementedError


class A(AbstractClass):
    def abstract_method(self):
        print("a")


class Bad(AbstractClass):
    pass


def f() -> AbstractClass:
    """
    find concrete implementation based on environment configuration
    """
    pass

b = Bad()  # mypy displays an error here:  Cannot instantiate abstract class 'Bad' with abstract attribute 'abstract_method'

x = f()
if TYPE_CHECKING:
    reveal_type(x)  # AbstractClass
```

This works because mypy checks methods marked with `@abstractmethod` even if the class does not inherit from `abc.ABC`.  But be warned that if you execute the program using python, you will no longer get an error about instantiating the `Bad` class without implementing its abstract methods.

Comment: Thanks for you answer. You solution however is exactly what I had in my original code: I simplified it for Stack Overflow to produce a minimum reproducing example.

The code in your answer outputs the same error as in my original post.

Comment: No it's actually not.  I added a concrete class, passed that to `f`, and used a `TypeVar` to ensure that the type passed to `f` is reflected in the result (I'll add some more to the example to clarify that last part).  As a result my code runs in python3 and passes in mypy, whereas yours fails in both.  (Note: I forgot to add a return statement to `f` in the complete example which I corrected).

Comment: Sorry, I was unclear: I also use a type var in the code that prompted me to write this post in the first place. I simplified the example for stack overflow.

My mistake, I didn't notice the concrete class. That doesn't solve my problem unfortunately since I really do want to pass an abstract class. My use case is something akin to a factory method where you pass a type and is returned a (concrete) subtype of that type.

Comment: Can you please improve the example code so that it demonstrates your problem.

Comment: I updated my response to include a solution that is closer to what the OP was originally looking for, though with some caveats